# How to create a spy on Date functions in jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have following function and spec. I have created spy on date objects which I am passing and manipulating in my function. But spy is not created on rightDate . Can you guys help me to solve this ?

```
 var jasmineFunc = new function(leftDate, rightDate){

    var leftDateFormat= leftDate.format("H:mm");

    rightDate= new Date(rightDate- 60000);

    var rightDateFormat = rightDate.format("H:mm");

    }

Spec:

describe("format", function(){

   var leftDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  var rightDate= new Date(2016, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);

   spyOn(leftDate,"format").and,returnValue("00:00");

   spyOn(rightDate, "format").and.returnValue("00:59");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors with your code.

- There is a comma(,) between and & returnValue, it should have been
  a dot (.)
- There is no function called format in Date object, my chrome
  certainly didn't suggest any method as such
- You have not used the ***it*** function which may be analogous to
  @Test in java (see code below)
- Answering your comment about a prototype, that should work too,
  please replace getHours with format on the spy to try it out.

However I've mocked a method [for your reference and it works](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/5/)

```
var jasmineFunc = function(leftDate, rightDate) {
  var leftDateFormat = leftDate.format("H:mm");
  rightDate = new Date(rightDate - 60000);
  var rightDateFormat = rightDate.format("H:mm");
}

Date.prototype.format = function() {
 return "This formats the text";
}



describe("format", function() {
 it('tempSpec', function() {
  var leftDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  var rightDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);
  spyOn(leftDate, "getHours").and.returnValue("00:00");
  spyOn(rightDate, "getHours").and.returnValue("00:59");
  spyOn(leftDate, "format").and.returnValue("I've hijacked it in the spy");

  var dt = leftDate.getHours()
  var txt = leftDate.format()
  expect(dt).toEqual("00:00");
  expect(txt).toEqual("I've hijacked it in the spy");
  })
});
```

- FYI Here is some more [information](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) for js date format, it uses the
  plain constructor to format.
- Also out of curiosity, may I ask you why you are trying to test an
  API code, you should be testing your own code because those API's
  have already been tested thoroughly

Here is an updated version of the code, I think I finally get what you mean by object getting changed, its being *reassigned*.
So what changed?

```
var jasmineFunc = {
  testFunc: function(leftDate, rightDate) {
    var leftDateFormat = this.formatFunc(leftDate);
    rightDate = new Date(rightDate - 60000);
    var rightDateFormat = this.formatFunc(rightDate);
    return {'left' : leftDateFormat, 'right' : rightDateFormat}
  },

  formatFunc: function(value) {
    return value.format("H:mm")
  }

}

Date.prototype.format = function() {
  return "This formats the text";
}


describe("format Spec", function() {
  it('tempSpec', function() {
    var leftDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var rightDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);
    spyOn(jasmineFunc, "formatFunc").and.returnValue("Some arbitrary Value");
        var testObj = jasmineFunc.testFunc(leftDate, rightDate);
        expect(testObj.left).toEqual("Some arbitrary Value");
        expect(testObj.right).toEqual("Some arbitrary Value");
  });

});
```

- Since you are reusing the variable, I've delegated the format to
  another function so that I can mock it per my requirement.
- Notice that I no longer have to mock the Date prototype, I can simple
  mock the intermediate function and hence you may reassign it as many
  times as you need.

Comment: Sorry to mention now, format is a prototype method of Date (Date.prototype.format = function(){....};     How can I create spy on these kind of methods ?

Comment: Check out the fiddle, updated it for you with the prototype.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I don't want spy on getHours . And spying on leftDate is straight forward here but rightDate Object is changing function and spy is not working on that

Comment: I do not follow how rightDate object is changing a function? May I know what you mean by changing w.r.t. code?

Comment: I guess I figured what you mean by changing. Refer to my answer(edited) or Link to fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/7/